# Snowflake Data Sharing - Grant partially executed | Grant not executed

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sql-grant, data-sharing

**Aim:**

Grant more privileges to the Data Share

**Description:**

> Please note that I'm using a 30 days trial version of Snowflake.

I've tried creating the Data Share via UI, but despite being able to **Add a Consumer** under the **Full Account section**, the user of that account was unable to Update or Insert the data shared.

[image]

The user of the account could only `select` data. But according to the [documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-sharing-intro.html) the user of the **Full Account** should be able to perform data manipulation (insert, update, etc).

[image]

I've also tried the manual way of creating the Data Share, but I kept getting the below Query Message

**SQL Code Sample:**

```
use role accountadmin;

create share SHARE_DATABASE;

grant usage,modify on database TEST_DATABASE to share SHARE_DATABASE;
--Message: Statement executed successfully.

grant usage,modify on schema TEST_DATABASE.PUBLIC to share SHARE_DATABASE;
--Message: Grant partially executed: privileges [MODIFY] not granted.

grant select,insert,update on table TEST_DATABASE.PUBLIC.TABLE_TEST_DATA to share SHARE_DATABASE;
--Message: Grant partially executed: privileges [INSERT, UPDATE] not granted.

--When trying to execute the grant for update only
grant update on table TEST_DATABASE.PUBLIC.TABLE_TEST_DATA to share SHARE_DATABASE;
--Message: Grant not executed: Operation not supported on a SHARE object.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snowflake shared databases are "read only" - please take a peek at the documentation at this link for more details:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-sharing-intro.html#introduction-to-secure-data-sharing

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Rich. I will accept your reply as the answer. Given that the shared database is "read-only", I am supposed to be getting those query messages. My original aim was to allow another user to have access and the ability to modify the tables within the database which I created. But I'll find another way or create another question for that. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

The error message are normal:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/grant-privilege-share.html

The document you refer says:

> Users in a reader account can query data that has been shared with it,
> but cannot perform any of the DML tasks that are allowed in a full
> account (data loading, insert, update, etc.).

The full account is the owner of the share.

Comment: Ahh The full account is the owner of the share..my mistake. Thanks for your reply Gokhan.